# undefined variable outside a for sentence with multiple events listeners in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

I want to build client side validation with Javascript validation API.

I did custom validation for some fields, but would like generic validation for all fields when empty. I am trying with a for phrase. But for some reason I got this error when I tried to run the variable [i] outside of for: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

This is my code so far.

```
//Test
var test_field = document.querySelectorAll(".um-form-field");
var i;

  for (i = 0; i < test_field.length; i++) {
            
            test_field[i].addEventListener('keyup', test_function, false);
            test_field[i].addEventListener('click', test_function, false);
            test_field[i].addEventListener('invalid', test_function, false);
            
            console.log(test_field[i].value);//this works every time i click or type a field!


  function test_function (event) {
            console.log(test_field[i].value);//This tells me an undefined variable every time I click on a field

            }
  }
```

**EDITED 24/12:**
Thanks to anyone. I finally used the event.target as mentioned in the comments.

This is my final code (im having some troubles with the setCustomValidity yet):

```
var all_fields = document.querySelectorAll(".um-form-field");
var i;
 for (i = 0; i < all_fields.length; i++) {
            
    all_fields[i].addEventListener('keyup', field_function, false);
    all_fields[i].addEventListener('click', field_function, false);
    all_fields[i].addEventListener('invalid', field_function, false);
            
  function field_function (event) {

    if (event.target.value.length == 0) {
            event.target.style.background = "#eb91ae";
            event.target.setCustomValidity("error");
            divError.style.display = "block";
            divError.innerHTML  = "You must complete this field"
            event.target.parentElement.appendChild(divError);
    } else {
            event.target.style.background = "#9deb91";
            event.target.setCustomValidity("");
            divError.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: where is your html

Comment: Use `event.target.value` to access the element handling the event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will not work.
after iterable `for...loop`, `i` will reach the end value, and here is `i` will be equal to `test_field.length` that why `test_function` will look like bellow when it executing:

```js
 function test_function (event) {
            console.log(test_field[test_field.length].value);

            }
```

So, the quick fix you can do like this:

```js
var test_field = document.querySelectorAll(".um-form-field");
test_field.forEach(field => {
    field.addEventListener('keyup', test_function, false);
    field.addEventListener('click', test_function, false);
    field.addEventListener('invalid', test_function, false);
});

function test_function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
}
```